# Django 1.10, hacer un update cada vez que se busca un elemento

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy tratando de que cada vez que busco un elemento en la base de datos un atributo se incremente en 1. Por ejemplo:

```
criterio = "Alberto"
resultado = Personas.objects.filter(nombre = criterio)
for persona in resultado:
    persona.coincidencias += 1
    persona.save()
```

Quiero saber si hay una forma más prolija y rápida de hacerlo, ya que este método degrada la performance notablemente (en la práctica esa query puede arrojarme cientos o incluso miles de resultados)

Comment: ¿Que versión de Django estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando Django 1.10. Ahí modifiqué el titulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo update() en conjunto con F:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

```
from django.db.models import F

criterio = "Alberto"
resultado = Personas.objects.filter(nombre=criterio)
resultado.update(coincidencias=F('coincidencias') + 1)
```

Comment: Te pasaste! Muchisimas gracias!